# Time not set right, date -u and hwclock -u yield different results

Tags: linux, time, hwclock

so i am having this weird problem with my clock on pc. I am currently using Kali Linux 2018.1.

Basically my problem is that my computer time is one hour behind every time i start my pc. So is my hardware clock. What i find even weirder is that ***date -u*** and ***hwclock -u*** display different results:

```
root@horse:/etc# date
Sat Mar  3 22:50:56 CET 2018
root@horse:/etc# hwclock
2018-03-03 22:50:59.654599+0100
root@horse:/etc# date -u
Sat Mar  3 21:51:03 UTC 2018
root@horse:/etc# hwclock -u
2018-03-03 23:51:09.904595+0100
root@horse:/etc#
```

The time from ***hwclock -u*** is the correct one.
Can you please help me understand and solve this issue?

Comment: What is your `/etc/localtime` linked to? (and if you boot 1hr early -- then your hwclock is set 1hr early, and you probably update sysclock on boot using ntp or similar) Set your time and then as root `# hwclock --systohc`

Comment: Take a look at [Time](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Time)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you for the answer! What i did was: `#hwclock -u > date -s` `#hwclock -w` and is ok now.

Comment: Glad to help. (just a hint - for any configuration issue you have, check the [Archlinux wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Main_page) first. It doesn't matter which distro you run, Linux is Linux under the hood. Arch, by being a minimal/purest distro, configures everything by hand, and they (by far) have the best information around collected in their wiki)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score -1):

Since `hwclock -u` showed the correct time:

```
#hwclock -u > date -s
#hwclock -w
```

This seemed to do the trick.
Alternatively :

```
#date -s M/D/Y +hh:mm
#hwclock -w
```